No nominees for moderator election: What happens next?
Stack Exchange’s position is that every site must have team of moderators to operate in our network. Currently this community is being moderated by eddex, who is doing a great job, but site moderation should never be just a one person job.
While sites are in Beta, elections do not need to be competitive. However, once a site graduates/loses the Beta label (which Cardano did in 2022), elections must be competitive to progress to the voting stage and be considered successful. We define an election as competitive when it has at least one more nominee than available moderator slots. This most recent election was for two moderator slots, so we would have needed to receive three nominations for it to be competitive, but unfortunately we received no nominations at all.
Members of an SE site being willing to step up as moderators has been the primary threshold for keeping a site alive since we created this policy in January 2015. Without that, a site is in danger of being shut down. Today, I am posting on behalf of the Community Management team to discuss the next steps for this site.
After a failed election we typically wait 6 months before trying again. In order for a future election to be successful, there need to be community members who are eligible to serve as moderators who are willing to step up to the plate.
Next Steps
We recommend waiting until April 2025 before setting up another election for this site. We’ll be looking for additional individuals to nominate themselves as moderators to join the team. If we can’t find at least three people willing to nominate themselves to be a moderator on this site by that time, the site is at risk of shutting down.
Do you have any questions about the election process, or any concerns keeping you from nominating yourself as a moderator? Let us know, and we’ll do our best to address them.
